# I would like to add Weekdays to this code

Tags: c++, c, datetime, dayofweek, weekday

Alright, so I have the following code:

```
   if (!clock_is_24h_style()) {
   if (current_time->tm_hour <= 3)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_NBC, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 4 && current_time->tm_min <= 29)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_ETODAY, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 4 && current_time->tm_min >= 30)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_9NEWSMORN, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 5)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_9NEWSMORN, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 6)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_9NEWSMORN, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 12 && current_time->tm_min <= 29)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_IMAGE_PM_MODE, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 12 && current_time->tm_min >= 30)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_NBC, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 13 && current_time->tm_min <= 29)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_WTC, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 13 && current_time->tm_min >= 30)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_BEARS, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 14 && current_time->tm_min <= 29)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_WTC, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 14 && current_time->tm_min >= 30)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_BEARS, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 15)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_NBC, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 16)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_9NEWS4, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 17)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_9NEWS5, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 18 && current_time->tm_min <= 29)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_9NEWS6, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 18 && current_time->tm_min >= 30)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_NN, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 19)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_NBC, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 20)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_WTC, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 21)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_BEARS, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 22)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_NBC, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour == 23 && current_time->tm_min <= 34)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_9NEWS10, GPoint(0, 0));

else if (current_time->tm_hour >= 23 && current_time->tm_min >= 35)
  set_container_image(&time_format_image, RESOURCE_ID_NBC, GPoint(0, 0));

else {
  layer_remove_from_parent(&time_format_image.layer.layer);
  bmp_deinit_container(&time_format_image);
}
```

It makes it so the image on the watch changes at a certain time, which is great and awesome works great.

However, the code cycles daily, and does this day by day making, and its only accurate during weekdays (Monday-Friday) and was wondering how I could make it so that code only apply to Monday-Friday, while a separate code will apply to Saturday and another for Sunday. Thank you!

Comment: Surely that code can be written a lot neater using a table?

Comment: I would definitely create an array of the resource you will set to the container. Do some math, based on the hours and minutes, that will represent the index of the right resource, and set that in one line of code. This if else control flow looks very combersome.

Answer (score 4):

The [`struct tm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) contains member `tm_wday` that holds the day of the week, where 0 is sunday and 6 is saturday.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not encapsulate your weekday image-changing code so that you could then create a set of Saturday image-changing code and Sunday image-changing code, and then branch to the proper set of image-changing code when entering this routine by determining the day of the week and then branching appropriately.